# Firebase permission denied for Catalyst app

Tags: ios, firebase, mac-catalyst

The iOS app works perfectly and can access the firebase database, but the Catalyst app gives the following error:

`6.11.0 - [Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] Listener at /my_database/path failed: permission_denied`

I have created an app in firebase console with the same bundleID of the Catalyst app and downloaded the and included the `GoogleService-info.plist` in the project.

**update**: the firebase rules for the path is as follows. note that the iOS app works perfectly and can access this database; only the Catalyst version gets the permission denied.

```
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "auth != null"
```

Swift that reads the database (works w/ no error on iOS):

```
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: RandomUser().randomUser, password: Constants.FIREBASE_P) { (user, error) in

            let databasePath = "my_database/battery_pdf/\(model)/odometer_values"
            let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: databasePath)
            ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                 ...

            }
       }
```

Comment: Are you literally reading at `/my_database/path`? Can you show us your rules and the code that does the reading?

Comment: thanks. Added firebase rules to the question. Yes, read from that path (names have changed, of course in the question). The iOs app reads exact same path (same code) with no error.

Comment: Can you also show the part of the code that reads from the database?

Comment: Added Swift code as requested.

Answer (score 2):

I added 
"Keychain sharing" as a capability and the error went away.
The app does not use the Keychain at all, so this is a strange requirement.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: FirebaseAuth uses the keychain